# Trouble with installation of Oracle 11g server version

Tags: oracle, installation, runtime-error

[image]

This error with the words:

> "[INS-20810] Target or command to 'Oracle Net Configuration Assistant' not valid" is shown at the end of installation when the net configuration has to be installed properly.

[image]

And then suddenly some error messages with the words **"An error occurred during runtime"**, pop up.

Then if I ignore the error messages and click skip, the installation gets completed leaving the essential net configuration and other database set ups uninstalled. Then when I get into sqlplus and enter the correct username and password too, it shows me an error with the message **"ORA-12560: TNS:protocol adapter error"**.

[image]

Comment: Please change "enter image description here" to some reasonable text describing the images.

Comment: You have to setup the net configuration manually, by creating a listener.ora and sqlnet.ora files. Also, if you want to connect using a TNS entiry,you need to create a tnsnames.ora

Comment: I just uninstalled my anti virus and then tried to install this. Then it got installed successfully. Thank you all!